# Assign value to dict in getter method

Tags: python, properties, getter

I would like to change a dictionary in the getter of a class before returning it. I can imagine that this question has been answered already but I cannot find it. There are similar questions that talk about reindexing/remapping of keys in a dict but they do not answer my question.
So, my assumption was that the getter returns `self._d` and then the key `a` is looked up and the value is updated. What confuses me is that the assignment `a.d['a'] = 2` does not change the dictionary.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._d = None

    @property
    def d(self):
        self._d['a'] = 4 # this line changes the behavior
        return self._d

    @d.setter
    def d(self, value):
        self._d = value

a = A()
a.d = {'a': 1}
a.d['a'] = 2
print("a.d: ", a.d['a']) # prints 4
```

Comment: It is being reset back to 4 by the getter in your `print` statement

Comment: If you look at `a._d['a']` after doing the `a.d['a']=2` and before the `print` statement, you will see that it *did* succeed in changing the dictionary.

Comment: @alani How did you look at ```a.d``` before the print statement? With my debugger (pycharm) I never see the value changing to 2.

Comment: I didn't. I looked at the underlying property `a._d`. Every time you try to look at `a.d` you will call your getter method and it will overwrite it, so I'm not surprised you don't see any change.

Comment: Indeed the answer that you have accepted does exactly that (examine `a._d`) - see paragraph starting "If we add more print statements"

Comment: I agree and did not think of the print statement calling the getter again, so that was definitely valuable input. Like I said, removing the print statement did not change the outcome, at least not in my debugger.

Comment: But I think the point is that when you try to access it in your debugger it is still doing effectively the same thing: if you are trying to check `a.d` rather than `a._d` then the getter will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what's going on here if you add print statements to each of your functions:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init is called")
        self._d = None

    @property
    def d(self):
        print("property is called")
        self._d['a'] = 4 # this line changes the behavior
        return self._d

    @d.setter
    def d(self, value):
        print("setter is called")
        self._d = value
```

And then we walk through your code:

```py
In [23]: a = A()                                                                                                                                                                                            
init is called

In [24]: a.d                                                                                                                                                                                                
property is called
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ebaff4a357c2> in <module>
----> 1 a.d

<ipython-input-22-687b3aea38f8> in d(self)
      7     def d(self):
      8         print("property is called")
----> 9         self._d['a'] = 4 # this line changes the behavior
     10         return self._d
     11 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

In [26]: a.d = {"a": 1}                                                                                                                                                                                     
setter is called

In [27]: a.d                                                                                                                                                                                                
property is called
Out[27]: {'a': 4}

In [28]: a.d["a"] = 2                                                                                                                                                                                       
property is called
```

First thing to notice is that calling `a.d` before assignment results in an error, because we haven't initialized the variable yet. (This isn't what you asked, just thought I'd point it out.)

Second, notice that the setter is called when you assign a.d the first time, but *not* when you update the key—the property method is actually called when you update the key.

If we add more print statements to print out the value of `self._d` and `value`, we can see that `self._d["a"]` does equal 2 before getting overwritten. First, we'll set the attribute equal to the dict, then we'll access the attribute.

```py
In [4]: a.d = {"a": 2}                                                                                                                                                                                      
self._d: None
value: {'a': 2}
setter is called

In [5]: a.d                                                                                                                                                                                                 
self._d: {'a': 2}
property is called
Out[5]: {'a': 4}
```

Using print statements like this to understand how these functions work can help you tease apart the functionality. Hopefully this helps you see the inner workings so that you can adjust your code to get the result you're going for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Comment: What Python versios are you guys running? I'm not able to see the property print :(

Comment: Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: What is strange is that I do not see this behavior in the debugger (pycharm). I agree that the assignment in the getter is done after ```a.d["a"] = 2``` so that the 2 is overwritten but I do not see key ```a``` set to 2 before  ```self._d['a'] = 4```.

Comment: @Thomas -- I added another short example to my answer showing what happens if you print out the values of `self._d` and `value` in the functions. It looks like calling `a.d["a"] = 2` doesn't actually do anything with the value of 2, because only the @property method is getting called. The setter only gets called when you try to set `a.d` itself.

Comment: @StevenRouk Cool, thanks! I understand now what is happening, but it's different from what I thought would happen. So, I learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

Actually your print at the end resets it to 4.
I would suggest you to take a look at the execution state in a visualization tool like http://pythontutor.com. You will understand what is going on

Comment: @alani When I remove the ```print``` statement and use a debugger ```a``` is still 4.

Comment: Just tried pythontutor, without the print statement at the end, self._d['a'] = 2.